# Spark SaveAsTextFile returns error - Py4JJaveError

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am doing a coursera class on big data management which has below exercise. Source code is available at below GitHub link

[SparkWorkCountLink](https://github.com/words-sdsc/coursera/blob/master/big-data-3/notebooks/Spark%20WordCount.ipynb)

However while executing the code I run into issue and saveAstextfile is not getting executed.

Below is the screen shot of the error.
[image]

[image]

Post update of java-jdk - error

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it helps to install `java-jdk` for Anaconda:

```
conda install -c cyclus java-jdk
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested - however I am still getting error - I have updated with new screen shot - error code has changed